# SQLite DELETE query won't delete from database

Tags: java, sqlite

Here's my code for the addStudent:

```
@FXML
private void addStudent(ActionEvent event) {

    // sql query to insert data into students at ID, first name, last name, email and DOB
    String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO students(id,fname,lname,email,DOB) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {

        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

        // add the data in the right column
        stmt.setString(1, this.id.getText());
        stmt.setString(2, this.firstname.getText());
        stmt.setString(3, this.lastname.getText());
        stmt.setString(4, this.email.getText());
        stmt.setString(5, this.dob.getEditor().getText());

        stmt.execute();
        conn.close();

    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And here's my code for removeStudent:

```
@FXML
private void removeStudent(ActionEvent event) {

    try {

        // sql query to delete data from the database
        String sqlRemove = "DELETE FROM students WHERE id = ?";

        // open a connection to the database and use PreparedStatement to 
        // initialize the query.
        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement delete = conn.prepareStatement(sqlRemove);

        // information needed to delete the row
        delete.setString(1, selectStudent());

        // execute and delete
        delete.executeUpdate();

        // close the connection
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // update table after deleting
    loadStudentData(event);

}
```

[image]

The picture above is the view of my table.  I hit LoadData and my table values show up.  I want to be able to click on a row(student) and hit Delete Student to remove it.

Helper method for removeStudent:

```
    private String selectStudent() {

String result = "";

try {

        String sqlSelect = "SELECT id FROM students";

        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sqlSelect);

        result = rs.getString(1);
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with when I "click" on a row, the id value for that isn't being held anywhere so when I hit "Delete" nothing is being given for it to Delete.

I don't know.  Any advice would be awesome.  :D

First edit: nothing is assigned to delete.setString(1, this.id.getText()).  When I click on the row and hit delete, nothing is happening because there's nothing being assigned to id when I click on the row. The query string DOES work however when I physically give it an ID to delete.  Also verified that the button does work; it prints out a lovely message for me with a good ol' System.out.println("expletive");

Second edit: Ok, so I updated the removeStudent code and now all I get is the string "null" returned.  Nothing deletes.  Nothing updates.  Nothing is happening except I get "null" in the console.

Third edit: Getting closer!  With the realization that the removeStudent isn't being given an ID to delete, I decided to create a private helper method that will do a SELECT query.  Now, when I hit delete, it'll delete....but from the top, and not at where I want it selected.  The code is above.

Fourth edit:  Getting even closer!  So, I figured out how to capture the row I click on within the table and I can delete......however, because of my sqlRemove command, I'm deleting by id so if I click on a row with index 3, then ONLY the row within the table that has an id of 3 will be deleted, nothing else.  I gotta re-write how the sqlRemove command is worded.

Comment: Have you actually tried checking the ID you get when you click delete?

Comment: you should check whether removeStudent is being called and print the value of this.id.getText(). Use a debugger and you will find the issue.

Comment: `System.out.println()` is the single most useful tool for debugging :)

Comment: Nothing.  Nothing is printing because Delete Student doesn't appear to even try anything.  

Weird.

Comment: Actually, never mind: it has to do with where the ID value.  Clicking on the table isn't setting anything so the delete.setString(1, this.id.getText()) is useless.  

How do I attach a value by clicking on the row?

Comment: I think you should debug this piece of code to know what exactly this 
`this.id.getText()` code returns.

Comment: I did: it's nothing.  this.id.getText() = nothing.

Comment: Basically, from what I can gather, whenever I click on a row, that id value isn't getting set.  So when it executes, nothing is being removed. 

I gotta figure out how to assign a value by clicking on it, I think.

Comment: I've came across [this](https://github.com/mapd/mapd-core/issues/45) - try to add an extra space after the question mark

Comment: Nothing: it still just prints "null" at the bottom with nothing being deleted.

Comment: If that doesn't help, try writing `dbConnection.getConnection().createStatement().executeUpdate("DELETE FROM students WHERE id = " + id.getText() + " ")` instead of this whole `PreparedStatement` - prepared statements are only useful if you reuse them (and you are always constructing a new one)

Comment: dbConnection.getConnection().createStatement().executeUpdate("DELETE FROM students WHERE id = " + this.id.getText() + "?");

Produces the same exact value to the console: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

```
    private String selectStudent() {

    // initial value for result to return
    String result = "";

    // grab the index of the row selected on the table
    int initial = studenttable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

    try {

        // SELECT query to execute
        String sqlSelect = "SELECT id FROM students";

        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sqlSelect);

        // while there's a next row
        while(rs.next()) {

            // set temp to equal the id rs.next() is currently on
            String temp = rs.getString("id");
            // get the row id - 1 since we start at 0
            int temp1 = rs.getRow() - 1;

            // if temp1 is equal to the index we selected
            if(temp1 == initial) {

                // make it equal to result
                result = temp;
            }
        }

        // close the connection
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // return the row to delete
    return result;
}
```

What's going on is in the comments.  I finally figured out how to pass the value from a selected row and compare it to a row.  Once I get the correct row to pass, I give it to the delete function to remove.

After a day in a half.............but I love it, so.  Yeah.